# Get the text of nth TD with all tr having particular class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The code which i am working on is as follows:

```
<table>
<tr class="warning">
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> name </td>
    <td> address </td>
    <td> phone no </td>
    <td> Location </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> 3 </td>
    <td> name2 </td>
    <td> address2 </td>
    <td> phone no2 </td>
    <td> Location2 </td>
</tr>
<tr class="warning">
    <td> 6 </td>
    <td> name5 </td>
    <td> address5 </td>
    <td> phone no5 </td>
    <td> Location5 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> 7 </td>
    <td> name6 </td>
    <td> address6 </td>
    <td> phone no6 </td>
    <td> Location6 </td>
</tr>
```

I like to get the text of all second TD with all tr with class warning.

I have tried using _.each method but wasn't succesful

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this

```
$('tr.warning').each(function(){  
    alert($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
    });
```

Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/NJRhy/)

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
$('tr.warning td:eq(1)').text();
```

if you want more specific answer than use `:nth-child` selector

```
$('tr.warning td:nth-child(2)').text()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbuZG/5/

Comment: i did not gave the full code just gave you the idea...now as per answer given by Alnitak you can map and get the result you need.

Comment: The `:eq(1)` syntax doesn't actually work, AFAICS - it only returns one element.

Comment: @Alnitak well i already tested and provided working solution withoutusing `.map()` and `.get()`

Comment: Yes, using `.text()` on its own is fine if you want the strings concatenated together.  You need `.map` and `.get` if you need an array of them.  Nevertheless, `:eq(1)` *doesn't* work.

Answer (score 5):

Using jQuery's `:nth-child` selector along with `.each()` should work for you.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chucknelson/KDy8X/

**Jquery**

```
$(function() {
    //use the :nth-child selector to get second element
    //iterate with .each()
    $('table tr.warning td:nth-child(2)').each(function(index, element) {
        var name = $(element).html();
        $('#name-list').append('<li>' + name + '</li>');
    });
});
```

**Some additional HTML:**

```
<div id="warning-names">
    Warning Names:
    <ul id="name-list">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: where `td` and `tr` define for `tr.warning td:nth-child(2)`..??? in your snippet..

Comment: I copied your HTML and it's in the fiddle, didn't want to paste that huge chunk of code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will obtain the list of names in an array:

```
var names = $('tr.warning td:nth-child(2)').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/CjQAh/

(using `:eq(1)` doesn't work, because the `:eq` applies to the index within the entire set of returned elements, not the element's position relative to its `<tr>` container, and so only returns one element).